# Are Physical Firewalls mandatory

Tags: architecture, security, server-side, ssl

I have a Delphi software application that uses non standard port nnnnn to nnnnn+50 with the FTPS protocol TLS 1.3
Until now I was suggesting my customers that the Server Side application needs to have

1. Public Static IP
2. Physical Firewall
3. Port Forwarding
4. No sharing of any Drives/Folders
5. Machine to be used exclusively for my application

I am considering relaxing the first two points by giving option of

1. DDNS
2. Trust the Router and Windows OS Firewall

Will this be safe enough as compared to my existing prerequisites ?
Will the router have to be used exclusively for my Server only or can there be other regular machines behind router ?

Comment: "safe enough" depends on the nature of what's going to be protected and what the risks are. Protecting nuclear weapons designs will have different requirements than Facebook for Cats

Comment: User backup data, for the user it will be as important as the former. Please advice where the loopholes are.

Comment: Depends what the user data is. Nuclear launch codes will have different requirements than pictures for a food blog.  _Nobody here can answer "safe enough" as we don't know what attacks you are trying to protect against._

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If by "physical firewall" you mean a separate appliance, then this might not be necessary. Configuring port forwarding in the router is already a kind of firewall.

But let's take a step back here. While there are security best practices, all security derives from a **threat model: what are you defending against?** Only understanding such threats make it possible to know what kinds of mitigation measures could be effective and appropriate.

Example threat: a server might unknowingly run vulnerable software that is accessible via some port, which could be located and exploited by attackers.

- Typical mitigation: the server is not directly exposed on a public network, but port-forwarding/NAT/firewall is used to only expose desired ports on the internet. The server can still hole-punch ports for outgoing connections.
- Potential additional mitigation in enterprise contexts: a firewall could try to perform intrusion detection in order to recognize scanning patterns from attackers.

Example threat: a network server with file system access might have broken file handling, making it possible for attackers to access or overwrite extra files (e.g configuration files, files from other applications, worst case: overwriting executables).

- Typical mitigation (general): the server software shall be the only application on the server computer, and the computer shall be easy to re-deploy from a known-good state in case of exploitation. For example, this can be achieved by running the software in a virtual machine that can be reset to a known-good snapshot.
- Typical mitigation (Linux only, though Windows Server also supports similar technology): run the server software in a Docker-style container. The processes in the container cannot see the host file system. Any changes in the container are forgotten when it is restarted, except for explicitly marked directories for read-write data.
- Corollary: persistent application data should typically be stored outside of a server, e.g. on a NAS or SAN that is not directly accessible from the internet, or is adequately secured. This often leads to a "DMZ" style network configuration.
- Corollary: application data needs regular backups to a different server.

Whether a static IP is needed or DDNS is sufficient is less of a security thing and more a question of whether the server can even be reached from the internet. When using IPv4, NAT is helpful for exposing multiple services over the same IP address.

Comment: Wow !! Thanks for the elaborate explanation, truly appreciate. From what I have understood it seems this model is secure unless there is mismanagement. All the same I humbly submit that we never know how tech changes and we can never be too careful.

Answer (score 2):

Every single day, new vulnerabilities are detected on lots of software components, be it on the server side or the router side.

First of all, port forwarding is nothing like a firewall. Port forwarding is port forwarding. Normally, you forward ports to a node in the [DMZ](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMZ_(computing)) which is separated from your network.

Why?

- routers [can get compromized](https://www.kaspersky.com/about/press-releases/2022_87-critical-vulnerabilities-discovered-in-routers-in-2021) and expose everything behind. Having a real firewall
  behind the router can delay attackers, the time for intrusion detection to play its role (e.g a detected portscan on the firewall should alert more than a port scan on the router).
- devices in the DMZ that receive port forwarding can also get compromized. Having a separate firewall prevents a too easy [lateral move](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Lateral_Movement) of attackers.
  For example firewall rules regarding specific trafic expected from dmz devices can block propagation of evil.
- firewalls that are running along other software on a node are vulnerable to other software vulnerabilities. E.g. a buffer overflow vulnerability on any of the other software might allow attacker to get control of the OS and [deactivate/neutralize the firewall](https://attack.mitre.org/techniques/T1562/004/). Running firewalls on dedicated appliances reduces the attack surface in this regard.
- [virtualization is not a sufficient](https://www.hitechnectar.com/blogs/hypervisor-vulnerabilities/) (even of the [network](https://jisajournal.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s13174-014-0015-z)) protection against attackers.

So, yes. Keep a firewall on a dedicated appliance. [Security is like an onion](https://twitter.com/zephrfish/status/1301498968044695554): The more layers you peal, the more you will cry. Moreover, if you (or your client) are on systems representing big money or used in critical infrastructure, you should  involve some qualified infosec professional, instead of asking random guys on the internet:

> If you think that it's expensive to hire a professional, wait until you hire an amateur
> - Red Adair